# What is the meaning of this sentence? (he talks about Plato as an old lover talks about his beloved)

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Would you explain the meaning and structure of this sentence? "he talks about Plato as an old lover **talks about** his beloved"

My question is Bold part(lover talks about).
....he talks about (Pluto = an old lover) or (Pluto = old lover talke about his beloved)??

Thank you so much.

---

The sentence was cited from amazon's book review of Republic (oxford) as following.
(and his crankiness in the endnotes (he talks about Plato as an old lover talks about his beloved) allows some great lessons about editorial practices and what's involved in the production of a scholarly edition.)

Comment: He ( the author) talks about Plato in the same way as an old lover talks about his beloved. It is a *simile* to express the idea of how mush he (the author) loves/likes  Plato.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much, Josh61. :)

Answer (score 1):

He talk about Plato as an old lover talks about his beloved.

In my opinion it's more like: the person A speaks about Plato as the person A would speak about his old lover who is his beloved.

So, person A has a feelings towards Plato, the same as the feelings he has as an old lover (towards his old lover) towards his beloved.

Plato isn't an old lover of person A, but he awakes the same feelings as an old lover would.

Comment: No. In the simile (as Josh61 says in a comment) the writer is likened to the old lover, and Plato to the beloved.

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. I see where I made a mistake, thank you.